# How to call python from javascript (nodejs) program, without creating child process

Tags: javascript, node.js, python-3.x

I have hardware running on nodejs, and I have written machine learning code in python3.
I want to call python3 program from nodejs (javascript) and pass data as arguments to python program.

I have found some of the methods like using spawn, python-shell, etc. which calls python by creating a child process.

But I want to call python from the parent process itself, without creating a child process. 
Means, only process, that is parent nodejs process should be running.

test.py

```
def someFunction():
  #some code here
  #print the arguments received.

someFunction ()
```

test.js

```
call test.py from this test.js and need to pass arguments to python program as well.
call test.py with arguments as ('xyz', 'abc')
```

I expect the output:
xyz
abc

Didn't find any way to call without creating and starting child process.

Comment: Python is an [interpreted language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language), I don't think there is a way to run uncompiled pure python code without starting an interpreter process.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You're spawning an external program, that needs a process of its own.

---

OK, that's not entirely true. You *could* write a complete Python interpreter or a virtual machine (which you could run an OS in and then run Python in that) in JavaScript and then you could run it entirely within the Node.js process … but that would be a huge amount of work.